# meekro db, json and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, meekro

I am using meekro db to fetch data from database and when I return object as json format then ajax call goes to error

```
  $(".cat").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({

        url:"/psl/ajax/get_words.php",
        method:"post",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{ id: value },


        success:function(response)    // success part does not execute
        {
            var data = JSON.parse(response);
            alert( data );
        },

        error:function (msg) {       // error part executes every time
           alert('error');
        }
    });

});
```

And the code which is being used to fetch data from database get_words.php

```
    <?php
    require_once '../inc/initDb.php';
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $words = DB::query("select * from words where category_id = '$id'");
    if (DB::count() > 0)
    {
        echo json_encode($words);
    }
```

Comment: put else part and try if (DB::count() > 0)
    {
        echo json_encode($words);
    }else { echo "not exists"; }

Comment: category_id  type integer or varchar ?

Comment: @JYoThI category_id is integer

Comment: I put else part but result is same

Comment: Then why enclosed it with single quotes . remove single quotes

Comment: I tried with Advanced Rest Client it gives desired result .... [{"id":"5","category_id":"1","name":"bed","area_id":"1","url":"","province_name":"Punjab","city_name":"Lahore"},{"id":"6","category_id":"1","name":"sofa","area_id":"1","url":"","province_name":"Punjab","city_name":"Lahore"}]

Comment: I removed single quotes but every thing is same